# Show a div only once per time the user is on the site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show a div element only once per time that the user is on the site. I've seen multiple answers to similar questions already, but none of them seem to work... I have a code written out, but it doesn't work... I got a part of the code from somewhere else (I can't remember) so is that why it doesn't work?

Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var once_per_session=1


function get_cookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + "="
  var returnvalue = "";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
      offset += search.length
      // set index of beginning of value
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      // set index of end of cookie value
      if (end == -1)
         end = document.cookie.length;
      returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
      }
   }
  return returnvalue;
}

function alertornot(){
if (get_cookie('alerted')==''){
loadalert()
document.cookie="alerted=yes"
}
}

function loadalert(){
document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = visible;

if (once_per_session==0)
loadalert()
else
alertornot()

//]]>
</script>

<div class="popupp" style="visibility:hidden;">hi</div>
```

Do you think you could help me figure out what's wrong with it?

**EDIT**

I've got it! Here it is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
(function() {
    var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
        document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = "visible";
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
})();
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="popupp" style="visibility:hidden;">hi</div>

</body>
```

Comment: is this really the code you're using? because you should at least get a syntax error, as you're missing the closing parenthesis of the `loadalert` function

Comment: @GNi33 Could you show me how I can fix it?

Comment: are you getting a syntax error or not? Just add the closing `}` after `document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = visible;`

Comment: @GNi33 I see what you mean now, but it still doesn't work... And I'm not even sure if I'm getting a syntax error because im testing it on htmledit.squarefree.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use localStorage instead, only when the user clears it out he will get the popup again (same with cookies) but its much simplier:

```
(function() {
    var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
        document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = "visible";
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
})();
```

html:

```
<div id="popupp" style="visibility:hidden;">hi</div>
```

This way you get a lot of less code. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I'm using it like this: <script>
var firstTime = localStorage.getItem('firstTime');
if (firstTime) {
    document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = visible;
    localStorage.setItem('firsTime', true);
}
</script>

<div id="popupp" style="visibility:hidden;">hi</div>

Comment: Add the script tag to the end of your HTML, just before you close the body tag. I believe the js gets executed before the html finishes loading.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ht1quLv0/ I put it here, and I'm not really sure what you mean by that :/

Comment: Check my edit now, You had a typo, visible should be "visible". In order to test it, in your console do localStorage.clear() in order to remove the visited flag from there.

Comment: You've done it, sir! Thank you very very much! I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/ht1quLv0/1/

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out :)

Comment: Wait... Gah, I think I messed it up again. This is what I got: <script>
(function() {
    var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
        document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = "visible";
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
})();
</script>

<div id="popupp" style="visibility:hidden;">hi</div>

Comment: You wont get the popup shown unless you do localStorage.clear(). remember the first time you get it than you wont because the flag.

Comment: localStorage.clear() would be something like clearing out the cookies ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to only show it once, you can use the [example on the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example_.233.3A_Do_something_only_once) as a start.

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
  alert("Do something here!");
  document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/pqb5baa5/

**Edit**

Here it is showing you div. Note, I moved the styling to CSS instead of inline in my jsFiddle - much better approach to get in the hang of

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = "visbile";
    document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/pqb5baa5/2/

Comment: Can I make it show a div instead of giving an alert?

Comment: @meowsom3 Yes! just change `alert('Do something here!');` to something like this: `document.getElementById(`popupp`).style.visibilty = 'visible';`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  in html: `class="popupp"` change  to `id="popupp"`

and in javascript: `document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = visible;`  change to  `document.getElementById("popupp").style.visibility = "visible";`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kgx3zuag/)