# Overlay 'welcome' DIV that appears only once, per user, per browser window

Tags: jquery

I am using this [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899415/show-a-div-only-once-per-time-the-user-is-on-the-site) article as guidance. I like [this](http://www.papermakestack.com/) welcome div that overlays on page load then fades out. I am trying to replicate my own, but where it only performs the function once, for each user.

The problem is clearly with my jQuery:

```
   $(function() {
        var showLoad = localStorage.getItem('showLoad');
            if (showLoad == null) {
                localStorage.setItem('showLoad ', 1);

                $('#load').show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#load').addClass("loaded");
                    }, 3000);
            }
    });
```

This works the first time, but then after this, the `#load` div stays fixed, without the `setTimeout`, addClass being applied. Web Storage sounds most suitable for this.

CSS:

```
.loaded {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden  
}
#load {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 500ms all
}
#load > p {
    top: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center  
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ag0bkr3/)

Answer (score 1):

It's working. You just need to add `display: none` to your `#load` div in the CSS, otherwise it'll never appear hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ag0bkr3/1/

Comment: Thanks! This has indeed solved it. If I open a new window on another browser, the welcome page loads. Interestingly, if I close the current browser, and view the page, the welcome div does not show. I had it in my head that local storage was erased when the browser closes. Is this not the case here?

Comment: No, the point of [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is to preserve values across sessions. Sounds like you are looking for [sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (though note that "session" has a somewhat different definition than "browser open")

Comment: Nah it'll only erase it if you're in an incognito mode window. A bit like cookies. And you're welcome. Upvote and set as answered if it answered your question :) thanks